# How to detect IoTHub configuration changes. Detect properties.desired changes and raise a event in Simulated Device. Need c# example.s

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I have to monitor properties.desired properties changes from SimulatedDevice app, if any change (in my case fwVersion change) in the properties.desired then immediately my SimulatedDevice should be notified and start download the firmware image.

Since I could not find a relevant sourcecode in C# to try it out pl suggest.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Nanda. Please can you share the code you have tried so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your SimulatedDevice is using the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client NuGet package to connect to your IoTHub, you can subscribe to the device twin updates. To subscribe, use the [DeviceClient.SetDesiredPropertyUpdateCallbackAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient.setdesiredpropertyupdatecallbackasync?view=azure-dotnet) method.

You can find an official sample in [this repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp). The file where they subscribe to the twin updates is [this one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/blob/master/iot-hub/Samples/device/TwinSample/TwinSample.cs).